# How to place a variable in jquery for attribute

Tags: jquery

How on earth do i get a variable (addcamstatus ) within the following;

```
var addcamstatus = camusers[i];

$('#onlineList').children('div').attr("name", ' + addcamstatus )
```

To clarify what i'm trying to achieve;

I want to target the src attr of an image that should indicate if a camera is on/off. The image resides within an Anchor tag that is within a div that is nested in another div. The top/parent div is "onlinelist."

```
var addcamstatus = camusers[j];
$('#onlineList').children('div').attr("name", addcamstatus).children("#play_tocam").children("img").attr('src', '');
```

the html:

```
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="ajaxChat_u_704" name="user"
data-gender="9" class="rowOdd">
UT <img class="GenderIMG" src="images/Genderfemale.png" width="15px" height="15px" />
<a href="#"><img src="img/profile.png" id="viewprofile" name="user" /></a>
user <a id="togglePrivChat" name="user" href=
"javascript:ajaxChat.sendPrivateMessageWrapper('/query%20user');"><img src=
"img/privatechaticon.gif" /></a><a id="play_tocam" href="#"><img src="img/cam.png"
id="getusercam" name="user" width="15px" height="15px" /></a>
```

Comment: this question is not clear at all , please clarify what exactly you want.

Comment: I made all of the html you posted actually display, but I agree with ProllyGeek I really have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well, you can see the a tag with id #play_tocam? There's an image in it with a src attr. I want to be able to select that and change its value if the value of the variable is the same as the name attr of the #online div's first child. The html you see is in the onlinelis div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#onlineList').children('div').attr("name",  addcamstatus )
```

`.attr()` takes parameters (or arguments), each separated by a comma. In your case you pass the string `"name"` as the first parameter, then a comma, then the variable `addcamstatus` as your second parameter.

Comment: Ok, would the following be logic to you to set the src attr to nothing? $('#onlineList').children('div').attr("name", addcamstatus ).children("#play_tocam").children(img).attr('src', '') ;

Comment: Without seeing the HTML it's hard to say. Although I imagine `children(img)` should be `children("img")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for. So simple. :-)

```
 var addcamstatus = textParts[j];

        $('#getusercam[name=' + addcamstatus + ']').css("display", "inline");
```